# Foundation 5 Block Grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<div class="medium-12 columns videos">
  <ul class="medium-block-grid-2 text">
    <li><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vid1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vid2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vid3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vid4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.video [class*="block-grid-"] > li {
  float: none;
}
```

What I am trying to do is only effect the block grid inside of the "video" div and have it "float: none" instead of "float:left" but I cannot seem to get it to work.

If I remove the .video at the front it works but it affects all the block-grids on the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="medium-12 columns videos">
```

In your html you have class as videos.

in css you have

```
.video [class*="block-grid-"] > li {
  float: none;
}
```

Change it to videos..

Comment: Thanks. That was my mistake. I have 1500 lines of SASS and sometimes my brain sees something that,s not there...like an "s". :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.video ul[class*="block-grid-"] > li {
  float: none;
}
```